# How should I put numpy in the list?

Tags: python, list, numpy-ndarray

I'm a student and I'm going to divide the wave file into 5 seconds and preprocess it with MFCC, Python

This is the full np.array of the file. And np.array divided by 5 seconds.

```
print(audios[0].shape)
print(audios[0][0:int(sr*5)].shape

(9091892,)
(220500,)
```

So I wrote the following code to divide it into 5 seconds with numpy.

```
audios_five = []
for i in range(len(audios)):#0~23
    print("audios"+str(i+1)+".wav")
    for j in range(len((audios[i])//int(sr*5))+1):
        audios_five[i].append((audios[i][int(sr*5)*j:int(sr*5)*(j+1)]).tolist())
        print("audios_five"+str(i+1)+"_"+str(j+1)+".wav")
        print(audios_five[i][j])
```

And that's the result.

[image]

I ask for your help me. I have no idea what the problem is...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `audios_five.append`?

Comment: Please don't include screenshots. Include errors as text. It makes it easy to search, copy and test.

Comment: Literally what it says, you're taking the index of `audio_fice` of the position that does not exist

Comment: Is there any reason why are you not using [numpy.split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

The problem is that the 'list index is out of range', meaning that `i` is not a valid index in `audios_five`.
This makes sense, given that `audios_five` is created as an empty list at the start of the code snippet. If you run the following (simplified) code, you get the same error:

```
test = []
test[0].append('something')
```

Yields

```
----> 1 test[0].append('something')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**The solution**

> For ease of notation, lets refer to `(audios[i][int(sr*5)*j:int(sr*5)*(j+1)]).tolist()` as `x`.

What is necessary depends on what you want to achieve.

*Option 1: Create a nested list*

I'm not much for dealing with audio in Python, but what your currently trying to do is append something to the first value in `audios_five` - i.e. create a nested list. If this is what you want, you first need an `audios_five.append(#create some item)` before you can `append` to this item with `audio_five[0].append`.

The result would be something like

> `audios_five = [[x1, x2, x3], [x4, x5, x6], ...]`

*Option 2: Create a flat list*

However, if you want a flat list, so you just want to append `x` to the `audios_five`, then you would be looking at using `audios_five.append(x)`.

The result would then be something like

> `audios_five = [x1, x2, x3, x4, ...]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't cut several audio files at once, but I was able to figure out how to cut one.